# How to set auto-number as external Id

Tags: externalid, auto-number

I am not being able to set a `Auto-number` field as an `external Id`. I read in a lot of documents that it can be done

Comment: Yes its possible. You have a checkbox 'External Id' when you edit an auto number.

Comment: I kept thinking it can be done during object creation. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a new Auto number field you get an option to make this field an External field.

You need to check that checkbox.

[image: Auto Number Field]

Comment: Thanks, I kept thinking it can b done during the object creation.